RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod Platform Not Supported Exception
We are experimenting with using RuntimeHelpes.PrepareMethod in order to "warmup" a .NET application so that the first request to an endpoint doesn't pay the price of the JIT compilation process.
When we call the method we are getting an exception with the message "Not supported on this platform".
We are doing the experiment locally on an M1 Mac so could this be a limitation of ARM64? What platforms don't support this approach?

This can be a combination of factors including both the target platform OS etc, and how the package is deployed (Native/AOT etc do not usually allow dynamic code); you can check at runtime via RuntimeFeature.IsDynamicCodeSupported. I do not know if there is an exhaustive list of permutations that allow/disallow runtime emit.
